# How can I support various screen sizes of mobile phones for my App in Android that supports only portrait mode?

Tags: android, android-xml

I am creating an App which which I want to make only for mobile phones and not the tablets. I understand I have to make layout folders and I have made following folders like
**1)layout-sw320dp**
**2)layout-sw480dp**
**3)layout-sw720dp**
**4)layout-sw600dp**

I want to know if this many are enough to support most of the screens and Could you give me example of each screen size that I should use? So, I can create emulator of that screen size to run and see how it looks in various devices. I am using xml layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to support multiple device use given lib below
you only have to manage one layout xml file and most of the device will cover using given lib 90% accurately

for DP use https://github.com/intuit/sdp

for SP https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: Can you tell me what DP and SP stands here ? I have created these fout layout folders mentioned above and added all the files to each and manually making changes as pe the need.

Comment: Hi Dp that means Density in pixel, and Sp means Scalable pixel.

better suggestion to support multiple device just create one layout under 
res/layout/whatever.xml 

and design your layout using this library's sp and dp whenever you want to give some margin like 5dp use this library's dimension. better way you will found in the github it self like how to use it with android.

Comment: check this one created for sample 
https://github.com/intuit/ssp/blob/master/ssp-android/src/main/res/layout/ssp_example.xml

Comment: This is more visualised example will help you out more in detail 
https://medium.com/@segunfrancis/how-to-build-for-different-android-screen-sizes-using-a-single-layout-resource-file-6e71ec3d9fcc

Comment: Okay, thank you . I will check it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

You click on the dropdown showing the text "Nexus 6P" and see a variety of sample screen sizes you can cater to.

Comment: You mean for creating android emulator, right ?

Comment: You do not need to, you can see the layout in the XML viewer itself. Just set some dummy data in XML you want to see and check it across a different number of screen sizes.